# Is there an easy way to track all my variable values in javascript?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am looking for a tool that will display all the values of my variables in a page all all times during execution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just use an object to store your values:

```
let obj = { var1: 'val1'm var2: 'val2'}
    
for (let i of Object.keys(obj)) {
    console.log(obj[i])
}
```

Can you provide an example or screen shot on what are you trying to do?

Comment: For every variable that I use in my program, I want to see what the current value is as the program is running. It would be nice there was a single page output that displayed everything.